# Bootstrap 4 popover not working properly?

Tags: javascript, css, spring, bootstrap-4, jstl

I implementing this in spring mvc web project, bootstrap popover comes on click of help icon.

On the other hand, at the first click on the icon; the popover opens and moves away from the help icon. after closing it, re-clinking, it correctly places the popover.

When I change the click, by a hover, on the first pass, the popover appears for a few moments barely seizable, the popover away from the help icon, then it returns to its position correctly.

If you look at this GIF image, you will understand better.

https://www.afnay.com/images/GIF.gif

I use JSP with JSTL.

I copy, all the code, without any difference, on plunker, and it works!
The code is on this plunker.
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/bcVtCYCpXgScBKcD

the difference, is juste i use tomcat 9 and JSP instead HTML.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQVHk.png)

Comment: The plunker link is incorrect, can you update it please?

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/bcVtCYCpXgScBKcD, thank you

Comment: i have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from picture in popover, when i change to use popover content with hided content, it work fine

```
                <div id="popover-content-logout" style="display:none">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="/ressources/images/image-goes- here.jpg" style="max-height:250px;" /> 
                </div>
                // popover declaration ...
                      content: function() {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id')
                        return $('#popover-content-logout').html();
                      },
```

I think that the loading of the image by tomcat takes time, knowing that in local I do not use the base 64 on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
data-toggle="popover"
```

to

```
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
```